# In Angular2 whats the simplest method for detecting scrolling for a component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm using Angular2 with Typescript and HTML5.

When scrolling occurs I want it to call a function in my component.

Normally in Angular 1 I would put a watcher on the scroll.
How do I do this for Angular2?

**This is my current attempt:**

```
  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event']) private onScroll($event:Event):void {
        console.log("Scrolling occurred!");
   };
```

But the console.log doesnt get hit.

Could you provide the html and typescript answer to the question.

Thank you

Comment: Then the scroll event is probably not emitted by this element. Perhaps a parent. Hard to tell without more context. `private` might not work with AoT for methods that have a `@HostListener()` decorator. (I don't use TS myself with Angular2 and therefore don't know for sure).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is there a javascript alternative I could use?

Comment: I don't know yet what the actual problem is. Listening for scroll events of the current component works the way you have it in your question. To know why it doesn't work in your case requires more information about your use case. Ideally a Plunker that also allows to investigate the problem directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rxjs to handle the event:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

let source = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'scroll');
let subscription = source.subscribe(e => console.log('scroll', e));
```

Now each time a scroll occurs, the source emits an event that you can listen to.

See:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-from-event